# universal_robot on Noetic: packages not found

Tags: ros, universal-robots

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I'm trying to connect ROS to a Universal Robots UR5, following this tutorial here:
http://wiki.ros.org/universal_robot/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20a%20Universal%20Robot%20and%20ROS-Industrial

To achieve this, I need the universal_robots package installed, which is part of the ROS_industrial stack.

To install ROS_industrial, I am following these installation instructions: http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Install

It states I should be able to install ROS_industrial using the command: `sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-industrial-core`, however this results in the message

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-industrial-core
```

I'm brand new to ROS, so any help is appreciated!
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 (64 bit) with ROS Noetic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355213/universal_robot-on-noetic:-packages-not-found/) by [TheAngusBurger](https://answers.ros.org/users/55876/theangusburger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I'm trying to connect ROS to a Universal Robots UR5, following this tutorial here:
> http://wiki.ros.org/universal_robot/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20a%20Universal%20Robot%20and%20ROS-Industrial

Please don't follow that tutorial.

We're in the process of marking those all deprecated, as they document the process for setting up the *old drivers*.

For any use of Universal Robots with CB3 and newer controllers (including the e-Series), use this driver instead: [UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver).

This is the *only* supported driver for Universal Robots robots, CB3 and e-Series. And the official driver.

> To achieve this, I need the universal_robots package installed, which is part of the ROS_industrial stack.
>
> To install ROS_industrial, I am following these installation instructions:
> http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Install
>
> It states I should be able to install ROS_industrial using the command:
> "sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-industrial-core", however this results in the message "E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-industrial-core".
>
> I'm brand new to ROS, so any help is appreciated!
> I am using Ubuntu 20.04 (64 bit) with ROS Noetic.

That package hasn't been released yet for Noetic, so that command cannot be used yet.

I'll update the instructions.

As I wrote above: please find the new, supported and official driver at `UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lrk](https://answers.ros.org/users/56958/lrk/) on 2020-07-24**:
"That package hasn't been released yet for Noetic, so that command cannot be used yet."

What ROS distribution do you recommend to work with the CB3 UR5 robot?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-07-28**:
I believe you've misunderstood my comment: the packages in `industrial_core` have not been released into Noetic. But those are not needed for UR packages.